# How to Pass Parameters to Main Method from another class?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

I have class that contains only a main method. I want to pass parameters to that method not from the terminal but from another class. How Can i do this?

```
public class class1
{
   public class1{}
}
public class class2
{
public class void main(String args[]){}
}
```

I want to pass An object of class `class1` to the main of `class2` . is That Possible??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an answer would span the entire subject of OO-oriented programming and as such is too broad for SO. Consider a tutorial instead https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: What have you tried? This question lacks even basic research, or evidence of an attempt. Also, you haven't explained what the entry-point of `class1` is or would be - merely that you have an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it as usual.

**Example :**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside Test class main()");
    }
}
```

The other class

```
public class Test2{  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Inside Test2 class main()");
        Test.main(args);
    }
}
```

Now run the Test2 class.

**Output:**
Inside Test2 class main()
Inside Test class main()

Comment: but in this case, it is just a static  method called, is not called as main method. What it means is JVM will not start a new application, a new java process, it will just execute the code from the main method (like any ordinary method). I am guessing the question was targeting a way to start an application in this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why they call it the main method. It is the first method that is executed when your application starts. And you cannot call it (as the main method), the JVM does it for you.
Of course you can call it like any other method, but it will not be called in the role of the main method but as any other ordinary static method.